# AngualrJS: One XHR call for all request

Tags: angularjs, promise

I have a .service() where I have defined all functions that my webApp can use to call (via $http) a REST API server. Now I have a page/route where a function in my .service() is called 2-3 times and this create 2-3 identical request to the REST API. This is my function:

```
getCities: function (redazionale) {
            return $http({method : 'get',
                url : urlwS+'/API/URL',
                headers : { 'X-CSRF-Token' : ipCookie('csrftoken')},
                data : { 'redazionale' : redazionale,'active' : 1 },
                cache: false
            })
        },
```

Is there a possibility to exec the call via $http just once and return for all others the $http promise ?

Thanks.

M.

Comment: errr: `cache: false`?

Comment: After you make the first call, store the response in a service. Next time when you make a call, check if the response exist. If it exist, don't make the http call, just return the object that you stored in a service.

Comment: @Quentin : I have tried with "cache: true" too.

Comment: @RocoCTZ your answer can work only if two call start when the first is finished, but this is not my case. However, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sure. Promises make caching insanely simple - just save the promise:

```
    var cachedCities = null;

    getCities: function (redazionale) {
        return cachedCities || (cachedCitices = $http({method : 'get',
            url : urlwS+'/API/URL',
            headers : { 'X-CSRF-Token' : ipCookie('csrftoken')},
            data : { 'redazionale' : redazionale,'active' : 1 },
            cache: false
        }));
    },
```

This will store the data in the promise in the first request and then all subsequent calls will use the cached data.